# how to find out the number of open sheets in workbook using VSTO

Tags: c#-4.0, vsto, add-in, excel-2010

I have a VSTO application where in a single workbook I open multiple sheets.
I have a situation where in I have to know which all sheets are opened at any given instance. Is there any any way to find out that ?

I am using C# with OBA.

Comment: What do you mean by "opened"? Unless there's something quirky about C#, Excel only has one `Active` sheet at any given time, and *all* sheets are *open* when the Workbook is open.

Comment: Ya sorry...Is there any way to find out all the active sheets along with names?

Comment: Yes. I'll post some info as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not a C# guy but you should certainly be able to obtain the information you're looking for. So the following examples are VBA but you should have all of the same methods available to you in C#.

To clarify as I mentioned in the comments on OP:

- Excel Workbook only has one `ActiveSheet` at any given time, and
- All sheets are "open" when the Workbook is open (but only one of them is the `ActiveSheet`)

To determine how many sheets are in the workbook, use the `Count` property of the `Worksheets` collection:

`w = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count`

To determine the name of the active sheet:

`sName = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Name`

If you have multiple open workbooks, and want to get the name of the active sheet in each of them (this just assigns to a string, but probably I would store them in an array so that I could refer to them later, if needed):

```
For each wb in Excel.Application.Workbooks
    sName = wb.ActiveSheet.Name
Next
```

You could do the same, or nest another `For/Next` if you want to store the names of all sheets in all workbooks:

```
For each wb in Excel.Application.Workbooks
    For each ws in wb.Worksheets
        sName = ws.Name
    Next
Next
```

Etc.